# T4 TextTemplatingFilePreprocessor .tt location at runtime

Tags: t4

I am writing an app that will process T4 files on client machines (outside of VS). Ideally, I'd like to embed the .tt file into the dll.

I tried setting Build Action to Resource, but I noticed that the preprocessed .cs file still contained a hard coded directory reference to the .tt file.

What is the proper way to distribute the .tt file and reference it at runtime?

To make sure I'm clear, I want to be able to either embed the file into the dll and access as a resource, or load the file at runtime from a location that is relative to the assembly path.

Comment: Do you really need to distribute the .tt file? The .tt file is transformed into a c# class that implements the behavior of the .tt at design time (preprocessing). At runtime you instantiate this c# class, feed it with parameters and run the transformation. If you are referring to the #line pragmas inside the generated c# file as "hard coded" file references - those help finding errors in the .tt file when there are compiling errors and have no impact on the runtime transformation.

Comment: Ok, so you're saying that I actually don't need to worry about the .tt files because of the class that is generated? What I find confusing is that the content of the .tt is not in the generated class, which leads me to believe the .tt is needed.

Comment: Using a t4 template consists of two steps: the first makes a compilable and runnable code class from it and is done by the templating engine. in the second step this code class is run and produces the output text (in your case c# code, maybe that's why it's confusing). The engine is not a redistributable part of Visual Studio, that's why you use preprocessed templates when distributing them. Preprocessed templates result in that code class that later writes your output code. This class contains of lots of "write" commands according to your previous t4-code.

Comment: If you can post your last comment as an answer, I can accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to distribute the .tt file itself. Using a .tt file results in two steps:

1. The templating engine transforms the template into some compilable and runnable code class.
2. This code class is run and produces the output code

The engine is not a redistributable part of Visual Studio, so, when you want to distribute your t4 template you need to use a preprocessed template. That way the code class generated in step 1 is rendered into the .cs-File of the t4 template, compiled and shipped with your assembly.

It might get confusing, when the t4 template is used to write C# code, because the code class of step 1 is also a C# class (in a c# project of course) and contains a lot of .Write() method calls that actually built up the desired output code.

The preprocessed template contains lines that start with #line followed by the local and absolute path to the T4 template file. Those lines are for debugging purposes and allow Visual Studio to display the proper line inside the .tt file when an error is found by the templating engine during step 1.